# Что нужно для написания операционной системы?

Tags: ос

Я имею ввиду с нуля. Какие языки программирования нужно знать? В какой программе писать?

И если можно, то поподробнее обо всем этом...

Comment: А смысл в создании своей операционной системы? просто такой вопрос - ради опыта или чтоб было? или вообще работать в ней самостоятельно? на это ведь надо убить кучу времени, и не факт что все будет идеально и красиво... вполне много ОС уже существует. Пользовались бы ими

Comment: оговорюсь что я не заставляю вас бросить это дело и не называю его гиблым... эо достаточно хороший проект, но смысла как такогого не вижу

Comment: Смотря что вы хотите от неё =3 Но, в любом случае, даже если вам нужно простая загрузка и переключение контекста задач (потоков), то читать надо будет много и трудиться тоже .з.

Comment: Еще одна ось? Пожалейте подневольных программистов, периодически получающих инструкцию "чтоб работало под виндой, линухом и макосью")

Comment: (1) И сколько подневольных программистов стонут под какой-нибудь MenuetOS. (2) Есть область, где новые операционки, хотя и весьма небольшие, появляются достаточно часто - микроконтроллеры.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если подходить по существу...

ОС - это такая штука, которая реализует многозадачность (обычно) и заведует распределением ресурсов между этими задачами и вообще. Нужно следить, чтобы задачи друг другу не могли вредить и работали в разных областях памяти и с устройствами работали по очереди, это хотя бы. А ещё надо предоставить возможность передавать сообщения от одной задачи к другой.

Ещё ОС, ежели имеется долговременная память, должна предоставлять доступ к ней: то есть предоставлять все функции для работы с файловой системой. Это минимум.

Далее. Платформа. От неё зависят инструменты, кои понадобятся для разработки ОС. Некоторые платформы: x86, x86-64, ARM, ну и куча других.

Почти везде самый первый загрузочный код должен писаться на ассемблере - там бывает куча правил, где оно должно быть, как должно выглядеть, что должно делать, и какой размер не превышать.

Для РС надо на асме писать бутлоадер, который будет вызываться BIOS и кой должен, не превышая четырёх с копейками сотен байт, что-то сделать и запустить основную ОС - передать управление основному коду, который в ближайшей же перспективе можно писать уже и на С.

Для ARM надо на асме делать таблицу прерываний (сброс, ошибки разные, прерывания IRQ, FIQ и пр.) и передачу управления в основной код. Хотя, во многих средах разработки такой код для почти любого контроллера имеется.

То есть, необходимо для этого:

1. Знать ассемблер целевой платформы.
2. Знать архитектуру процессора и всякие служебные команды и регистры, чтобы настроить его для работы в нужном режиме. В РС это переход в защищённый режим, например, или в 64битный режим... В ARM - настройка тактирования ядра и периферии.
3. Знать, как именно будет запускаться ОС, куда и как нужно пихать свой код.
4. Знать язык С - большой код на асме написать затруднительно без опыта, поддерживать его будет ещё труднее. Посему надо ядро писать на С.
5. Знать принципы работы ОС. Ну, книжек на русском языке по этой теме много всяких, правда, не знаю, все ли они хорошие.
6. Иметь много-много терпения и усидчивости. Ошибки будут и их надо будет искать и исправлять. А ещё надо будет очень много читать.
7. Иметь много-много времени.

Далее. Допустим, вы что-то написали. Надо это дело тестировать.
Либо надо устройство физическое, на коем будут идти эксперименты (отладочная плата, второй компьютер), либо эмулятор его. Второе обычно использовать и проще, и быстрее.
Для PC, например, VMWare.

Статей по этой теме в интернете тоже достаточно, если хорошо поискать. А также есть множество примеров готовых ОС с исходниками.

Даже можно при большом желании посмотреть исходники старого ядра NT-систем (Windows), как отдельно (кое микрософтом выложено, с комментариями и разного рода справочными материалами), так и в совокупности со старыми же ОС (утекло).

Comment: Хороший, годный подробный ответ.

> Для РС надо на асме писать бутлоадер,

можно и на Си. Тем более, что EFI уже идет в массы. И те же новомодные "БИОСы" (EFI) пишут уже более, чем на 90% на Си.

> Посему надо ядро писать на С.

Да, только вот ООП подход все равно используют. Думаю, что возможно использовать и C++ для написания ядра, но оно при это станет существенно "тяжелее" и непереносимее с платформы на платформу.

Comment: Вот я, к сожалению, не интересовался EFI, посему не в курсе=)

Угу, я бы тоже тут с++ не стал пользовать. Хотя я знаю, что IAR для ARM позволяет пользовать C++ в качестве компилятора, по-моему. Но вот зато у остальных с этим сложности =) Да и С-то, как показал опыт, с одного компилятора на другой не так-то просто всегда перенести (если заранее не учитывать) - у всех свои стандарты...

К счастью, ООП-подход можно и на самом С реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

Язык - [ASM](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Язык_ассемблера). Как например, проекты: [BareMetal](http://www.returninfinity.com/baremetal.html) и [MenuetOS](http://www.menuetos.net/). Оба с открытыми исходниками.

Comment: Ибо ASM - это круто? :) На самом деле подойдёт язык, для которого кто-то уже написал транслятор (кодогенератор транслятора для этой архитектуры). Или написать его самому. На это тему полезно посмотреть на gcc - там кодогенераторов до этого, до самого... И, соответственно, новая архитектура добавляется проще.

Comment: Не потому что круто, а потому что раз уж человек собрался писать свою Ось, то он должен понимать как там все будет происходить на самом низком уровне. Имхо, конечно.

Comment: Знание ассемблера и понимание процессов на низком уровне не эквивалентно.

Comment: Не спорю.

Comment: Понимание, в какие последовательности команд будет транслироваться код во многих местах ядра и драйверов необходимо. Мне больше всего нравится C c ASM вставками по необходимости. В конце концов памяти сейчас хоть залейся.

Answer (score 1):

- На английском: [Write Your Own Operating System](http://www.superfrink.net/athenaeum/OS-FAQ/os-faq.html).
- На русском: [Операционные системы. Разработка и реализация](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3092042/).

Answer (score 0):

В гугле информации на эту тему более чем достаточно. Если вы будете делать сами, с нуля, то дальше загрузчика (BootLoader) вы не дойдете. Посему рекомендую вам проштудировать гугл на данную тему, скачать уже более менее готовое решение, например [VictoriaOS](http://victoriaos.org.ru/), изучить сырци и попытаться внести свои изменения. Это принесет гораздо больше пользы нежели вы будете писать всё с нуля.

Comment: BootLoader в традиционном для ОС виде можно и не писать. Например можно использовать ДОС, там запустить свою программу, которая заменит вектора прерываний, включит защищенный режим, настроит MMU и т.д.

Однако, писать еще одну традиционную ОС вряд ли стоит. Лучше подумайте о динамической распределенной системе для мобильных устройств (нам ведь обещают, скажем, Wi-Max повсеместно), о системе действительно облачных вычислений (не мобильный КЛИЕНТ-СЕРВЕР (пусть даже не-знаю-какой-конкретно-сервер)).

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте Торвальдса "Just for Fun".

Answer (score 0):

Например, можно начать [так](http://www.realcoding.net/article/view/2205). Но лучше для начала ознакомиться со старыми версиями Linux и учебной операционной системой Minix. Попробовать скомпилировать их в разных режимах и произвести свои модификации.

Comment: Или операционкой Contiki - вполне себе работающая :)